# Rails accesskeys for left and right arrows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does rails support left and right arrow keys in the :accesskey attribute?

```
= link_to "< Previous", @vehicle.previous, :accesskey => "LEFT ARROW"
= link_to "Next >", @vehicle.next, :accesskey => "RIGHT ARROW"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not rails responsibility. Probably you need some js plugin that binds key presses to links.

If you want to add some attributes into generated `<a>` tag, use `:html_options` key

```
= link_to "< Previous", @vehicle.previous, :html_options => {:accesskey => "LEFT ARROW"}
```